# Is it really worth to spend time on Telegram Crypto Contest?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, password-cracking, diffie-hellman

[Telegram](https://telegram.org/) is running [this](https://telegram.org/blog/cryptocontest) crypto contents. But what I heard from some people on the web is that they designed the contest in such a way that they made it practically impossible to crack.

Is it really worth the efforts & time, atleast from a learning point of view if not crackable?

Or it will be a waste of time attempting it.

Answer (score 2):

Telegram was hosting a similar contest last year where they also offered a bounty, but the only attack vector they were accepting was passive eavesdropping on the traffic of one user. This was widely criticized as an unfairly restricted contest which was far away from a realistic attack scenario.

This new contest, however, allows a much wider array of possible attack vectors, including MITM, chosen plaintext and a malicious server, making it much more realistic. Common attack vectors which are still not accepted are placing malware on the clients or using social engineering, but this is a reasonable restriction because there is no technical method to defend against them.

As a learning exercise, it might be worth trying to learn how to implement a secure chat protocol. However, when you are a beginner at hacking and believe that you might be able to get rich here, you will be in for a disappointment. Telegram is confident enough that they are willing to bet $300,000 and their reputation that you are wasting your time.